# swift wkwebview httponly cookies set value

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview

In wkwebview can we set the httponly value of the cookies? Is there any way we could do this from swift?

```
                if let newCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
                    .domain: "." + domain,
                    .path: "/",
                    .name: cookie.name,
                    .value: cookie.value,
                    .isHttpOnly: true
                ])
```

I've tried setting the isHttpOnly value but it's get only attribute from HTTPCookie class.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the documentation for Cookies "Cookies can be marked as HTTP-only by a server (or by JavaScript code)" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookie/1392969-ishttponly.  So no, you cannot set this.  And you should not need to. Ask your server devs.